# How precise will a calculation of Jerk be based upon accelerometer data from a smart-phone?

Tags: android, ios, signal-processing, accelerometer, sensors

I understand you need to filter the accelerometer results to get as much noise away as you can. There are plenty of discussions of that in here. But when you get past that and you calculate Jerk over say a 20 minute, 10hz filtered data stream from a smart-phones accelerometer, how big is the remaining noise we can't filter away? (from hardware, that Jerk is a derivative, etc) Is this noise such that in fact we cant put much faith in the Jerk estimate we get to? Could one calculate a confidence measure for the Jerk estimate?

Answer (score 0):

Differentiating acceleration is a kind of high-pass filtering operation, so it amplifies the high frequency noise.

If you apply a low-pass filter before or after, then you can suppress that high frequency noise, so your jerk signal won't be too noise -- I don't know if 10Hz is low enough, but it'll be somewhere around there.

Unfortunately the high-pass filter is going to remove a lot of your jerk information.  Whether or not what remains is "accurate" really depends on what you want to use it for.  If the phone is hand-held, then there are physical limits to the amount of jerk that can be applied, and you can probably do a reasonable job.